# How do fetch an unlimited number of rows in Presto?

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I got `In strict mode, if ORDER BY is specified, LIMIT must also be specified`, so I can't just omit the `limit`. I need to fetch a few billion rows, so I tried have a higher limit: `limit 10000000000`. However, I got `FAILED: NumberFormatException For input string: "10000000000"`.

Removing strict mode isn't an option. How else would I return a few billion rows?

Comment: The 'limit' should use an Integer field. Kindly check the field used.It must be an Integer rather than a String. Even if it an Integer, the limit is 2^31 -1. And the value which you have mentioned is out of range for Integer.Use appropriate data type to get the required value range.

Comment: Do you know why was this limitation over ORDER BY created in the first place?

Comment: @KeshavPradeepRamanath I need more than 3 billion rows.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz no idea.

Comment: Currently ORDER BY is implemented by moving the data to a single node. Does moving 3 billions rows to a single node sounds like a good idea?